# Does language acquisition become more difficult after a "critical period" linked to age?

Tags: language, learning

The critical period hypothesis (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_period_hypothesis)):

> The critical period hypothesis is the subject of a long-standing
>   debate in linguistics and language acquisition over the extent to
>   which the ability to acquire language is biologically linked to age.
>   **The hypothesis claims that there is an ideal time window to acquire
>   language in a linguistically rich environment, after which further
>   language acquisition becomes much more difficult and effortful.**
>
> In second-language acquisition, the strongest evidence for the
>   critical period hypothesis is **in the study of accent, where most older
>   learners do not reach a native-like level**.

Is it true that there is an ideal time window to acquire language, after which further language acquisition becomes more difficult?

Do most older learners never acquire a native-like accent in a second language? Do most older learners also never acquire native-like grammar?

Comment: Whether it's worthwhile is off-topic, but whether it's *possible* to be able to speak a language fluently after adolescence is on-topic.

Comment: True, I was interjecting my opinion into it, but the question still stands to see if it is at all possible, practically speaking.

Comment: I do recognize that a few people have been able to achieve native-like fluency to the point that natives mistake them for one. But I just want to know if this level of fluency is accessible to the majority of language learners, and not just geniuses.

Comment: Anecdotally, yes, for example if you marry someone and live in their country for a couple of decades.

Comment: Ditto, met a Russian lady who had to learn Dutch to get her citizenship here. She spoke it fluently after only 2-3 years. Helped she learned German as a student in Russia, and married a Dutch person. Ditto, my mother only learned German late in life, and speaks it well enough to pass for a native of a German speaking country in one (though not necessarily a native of that country, she's called a German in Austria and an Austrian in Germany...).

Comment: I strongly believe that it is totally possible for 90% of people and I've seen several people to do that. But I cannot prove it.

Comment: See *Bilingualism in Development: Language, Literacy, & Cognition* by Ellen Bialystok, pages 71-87, for a modern account that's critical of the critical period hypothesis.

Comment: http://www.sirrichardfrancisburton.org/rfb_languages.html

Comment: @rob 'What I just said' makes less sense since you deleted your comment to which I was replying. :) I was suggesting that it matters less what the OP was asking, and matters more what the quoted claim is stating: i.e. the quoted claim defines "native-like fluency" with a particular emphasis on "accent".

Comment: @ChrisW Nah, I read your respond before deleting my preceding comments (trying to keep the space clean) what you said didn't make sense until your latest comment. I'm not sure that an accent implies native fluency though outside of some nuances as noted in the shibboleths though, that's starting to touch into the area of linguistics where I've seen disagreements between the experts and the native-speakers.

Comment: I edited the question to match the quote that @FivePoints supplied.

Comment: Maybe I didn't communicate myself well enough as to what I am looking for: how realistic is it that a foreigner past adolescence can speak English(in this case) just like you?

Comment: @ChrisW, yes, I can definitely see that happening. So for the most part, it's almost impossible to do it, outside of taking measures such as the one you described.

Comment: Not impossible -- people can often become [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluency) in a foreign language in much less time than "decades" (and without marrying), even when they are not 'natively' [bilingual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilingual). I do think that some "immersion" in the language is probably helpful.

Comment: @FivePoints "*Do most older learners also never acquire native-like grammar?*" Nobody has claimed that. It is an off-topic question.

Comment: @ChrisW, yes, but learners also lack one thing which they can never makeup: a childhood in that language. That's something native speakers will always hold over non-natives.

Comment: @FivePoints How do you know that lacking a childhood in a language can't be made-up for (when considering native-like fluency)? If that is the case, then that is your answer, and you should write it with references.

Comment: @Articuno, the question has changed dramatically from it's original meaning. I wanted to ask if it was impossible to speak like a native speaker after a certain point, not that it becomes more difficult to simply acquire a second-language, which can include many different levels of proficiency.

Comment: @FivePoints You provided a quote that made certain claims. To be on-topic, questions are restricted to challenging the notable claims demonstrated by the quote. Since the quote doesn't claim it is impossible, a question asking about impossibility is off-topic.

Comment: @Articuno, so what you're telling me is that in order to have that specific question answered, all I need to do is look for a source claiming such a thing?

Comment: @FivePoints Yup! There's a bit more to it (http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2507/5582), but that is pretty much correct.

Answer (score 4):

Before I get into detail, I'd like to make a few remarks regarding the questions and their possible pitfalls.

First of all, it is not easy to assess how difficult it is for young children to learn a language because they cannot provide you with cognitive feedback until a certain age. That is why "more difficult" lacks a starting point that it can be compared to and in any case there is still a lot of ground for subjectivity when it comes to difficulty.

As to the question about whether most older learners never acquire a native-like accent, the answer is most likely 'yes'. But I strongly believe it is not the result of some critical period but rather the external factors and approach. For more information, see below.

The CPH (Critical Period Hypothesis) popularized by Eric Lenneberg has been the subject of lively debate among scholars ever since its conception. In the case of first language acquisition,

> <...> the hypothesis is difficult to test directly because cases of
> linguistic deprivation during childhood are fortunately rare. <...>
>
> Many researchers have hypothesized that young children are predisposed to the acquisition of language (Chomsky, 1959; Lenneberg, 1967; Newport, 1990) and further that this disposition is unique to childhood. Lenneberg (1967) formally proposed a critical period for language acquisition that extends from infancy until puberty. Although the exact timing (Johnson & Newport, 1989; Krashen, 1973; Lenneberg, 1967) and nature (Lenneberg, 1967; Newport, 1990) of the critical period are matters of debate, there is a great deal of indirect evidence to support the hypothesis (Basser, 1962; He´caen, 1976; Johnson & Newport, 1989, 1991; Lenneberg, 1967). Direct evidence, in the form of individuals who were deprived of linguistic input during
> the proposed critical period, is more rare, and the interpretation of these cases is often ambiguous (Curtiss, 1977; Mayberry & Eichen, 1991; Skuse, 1993). ([1](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/%7Eskang/371/DownloadablePapers/BongaertsEtAl97.pdf))

Also,

> ...it should be noted that, while the postpubescent
> learners did not reach as high a level of proficiency as the native or early
> learners, language had not become totally unlearnable for them. This
> rules out any extreme interpretation of the critical period hypothesis. ([2](https://static.squarespace.com/static/512c2269e4b091ea7fcc8dfa/t/51ba54c5e4b086f6858a79cd/1371165893936/Grimshaw%20et%20al.%20-%201998%20-%20First-Language%20Acquisition%20in%20Adolescence%20Evidence%20for%20a%20Critical%20Period%20for%20Verbal%20Language%20Development.pdf))

In the case of second language acquisition, the evidence is mixed.

> Scovel's (2000) review indicates that during the 1980s expert opinion swung away from the CPH. It was influenced no  doubt by a number of negative evaluations of early language learning at school (e.g. Burstall et al, 1974) which indicated that the initial gains from making an early start
> at primary school had largely evaporated within a few years at secondary school. In
> recent years however opinion has begun to swing back again. Initially the CPH
> focused mainly on speech (native-like accent) but in recent years has been extended
> to embrace other aspects of language competence such as grammar (particularly
> morphology and syntax), opening up the possibility that there may not be one 'critical
> period' which applies at the one time 'across the board' but that different aspects of
> language competence may go through different periods which are particularly
> sensitive for their development.
>
> Marinova-Todd et al 's (2000) review, on the other hand, is more
> sceptical about the  CPH, pointing to thirty-five fairly recent
> studies, of which fourteen seemed to offer  some support for the CPH,
> with twenty-one providing negative evidence. Several of  these
> studies, they claim, show that learners post-puberty are in fact
> capable of  achieving native-like competence. In particular they claim
> that those favouring the  CPH have committed three fallacies:
> misinterpretation, misattribution and  misemphasis¹.([3](http://www.bcs.rochester.edu/people/newport/pdf/Johnson_NewportCogPsy89.pdf))

The excerpt has an interesting footnote that elaborates on possible misconceptions arising from what seems obvious versus what may be the case:

> ¹ Marinova-Todd, Marshall and Snow (2000) accept that generally adults
> achieve lower levels of proficiency than younger learners do, but they
> attribute this to contextual rather than to biological factors. They
> claim that those favouring the CPH fall victim to three fallacies:
> 'The first fallacy is misinterpretation of observations of child and
> adult learners, which might suggest that children are fast and
> efficient at picking up second languages. Hard data make it clear that
> children learn new languages slowly and effortfully - in fact, with
> less speed and more effort than adolescents or adults. The second
> fallacy is misattribution of conclusions about language proficiency to
> facts about the brain; connections between brain functioning and
> language behaviour will no doubt in time be confirmed, but their exact
> nature cannot even be guessed from the data currently available on
> brain functions in early versus late bilinguals. Finally, the common
> fallacy of reasoning from frequent failure to the impossibility of
> success has dogged second language research. Most adult second
> language learners do, in fact, end up with lower-than-native-like
> levels of proficiency. But most adult learners fail to engage in the
> task with sufficient motivation, commitment of time or energy, and
> support from the  environments in which they find themselves to expect
> thigh levels of success. …… this misemphasis has distracted
> researchers from focusing on the truly informative cases:  successful
> adults who invest sufficient time and attention in second language
> acquisition and who benefit from high motivation and from supportive,
> informative second language  environments.([3](http://www.bcs.rochester.edu/people/newport/pdf/Johnson_NewportCogPsy89.pdf))

I will address the question about native-like accent with the following citation:

> A number of recent studies, e.g. Bongerts et al (1997), Nikolov (2000a), Bellingham
> (2000), and Neufeld (2001) all suggest that adults are in fact capable of attaining a
> native-like accent, which runs counter to the CPH. Nikolov's study featured thirty three
> successful language learners aged 20 to 70, all of whom had acquired their
> target language after puberty. Of these, twenty were of different first languages
> learning Hungarian and thirteen were of Hungarian as first language learning
> English. She found that, as judged by three groups of native speakers, six of the
> learners of Hungarian and five of the learners of English were either generally or
> often mistaken for native speakers, and she concludes that this calls any strong
> version of the CPH into question. Her survey showed that 'these successful language
> learners want to sound like natives, they share intrinsic motivation in the target
> language which is often part of their profession, or they are integratively motivated.([3](http://www.bcs.rochester.edu/people/newport/pdf/Johnson_NewportCogPsy89.pdf))

Another paper that you might be interested in reports on two studies that carefully screened a group of successful late second language learners that mastered a native-like accent:
[SSLA, 19, 447-465. *Age and Ultimate Attainment in the pronunciation of a foreign language*. By Theo Bongaerts, Chantal van Summeren, Brigitte Planken, and Erik Schils](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/%7Eskang/371/DownloadablePapers/BongaertsEtAl97.pdf)

---

[(1)](https://static.squarespace.com/static/512c2269e4b091ea7fcc8dfa/t/51ba54c5e4b086f6858a79cd/1371165893936/Grimshaw%20et%20al.%20-%201998%20-%20First-Language%20Acquisition%20in%20Adolescence%20Evidence%20for%20a%20Critical%20Period%20for%20Verbal%20Language%20Development.pdf) BRAIN AND LANGUAGE 63, 237–255 (1998) ARTICLE NO. BL971943
*First-Language Acquisition in Adolescence: Evidence for a Critical Period for Verbal Language Development.* By Gina M. Grimshaw, Ana Adelstein, M. Philip Bryden,† and G. E. MacKinnon.

[(2)](http://www.bcs.rochester.edu/people/newport/pdf/Johnson_NewportCogPsy89.pdf) COGNITIVE PSYCHOLOGY 21, 60-99 (1989)
*Critical Period Effects in Second Language Learning: The Influence of Maturational State on the Acquisition of English as a Second Language.* By JACQUELINE S. JOHNSON AND ELISSA L. NEWPORT

[(3)](http://www.coe.int/t/dg4/linguistic/source/johnstoneen.pdf) ADDRESSING 'THE AGE FACTOR': SOME IMPLICATIONS FOR LANGUAGES POLICY
*Guide for the development of Language Education Policies in Europe From Linguistic Diversity to Plurilingual Education. Reference Study.* By Richard JOHNSTONE. 2002